# MsSQL iterate through result to check and fetch more data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm doing query on our events table

```sql
SELECT id, user_id, date, time, event_type_id FROM events
WHERE date >= '2018-05-01'
AND event_type_id = 3
```

This returns something like this

```sql
+------------+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| id         | user_id     |          date           |          time           | event_type_id  |
+------------+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
|    5550579 |        1887 | 2018-05-03 00:00:00.000 | 2000-01-01 08:10:46.000 |              3 |
|    5550581 |        1887 | 2018-05-03 00:00:00.000 | 2000-01-01 08:41:38.000 |              3 |
|    5550629 |         993 | 2018-05-03 00:00:00.000 | 2000-01-01 08:01:59.000 |              3 |
|    5550662 |         546 | 2018-05-03 00:00:00.000 | 2000-01-01 09:13:04.000 |              3 |
|    5550711 |        1869 | 2018-05-03 00:00:00.000 | 2000-01-01 09:05:58.000 |              3 |
|    5550730 |        1148 | 2018-05-03 00:00:00.000 | 2000-01-01 09:15:20.000 |              3 |
|    5550732 |         611 | 2018-05-03 00:00:00.000 | 2000-01-01 09:26:26.000 |              3 |
|    5550733 |         627 | 2018-05-03 00:00:00.000 | 2000-01-01 09:26:32.000 |              3 |
|    5550734 |         530 | 2018-05-03 00:00:00.000 | 2000-01-01 09:27:32.000 |              3 |
|    5550767 |         566 | 2018-05-03 00:00:00.000 | 2000-01-01 09:50:15.000 |              3 |
|    5550810 |         415 | 2018-05-03 00:00:00.000 | 2000-01-01 10:10:01.000 |              3 |
|    5550812 |         556 | 2018-05-03 00:00:00.000 | 2000-01-01 10:14:08.000 |              3 |
|    5550878 |         777 | 2018-05-03 00:00:00.000 | 2000-01-01 10:39:19.000 |              3 |
|    5550896 |         926 | 2018-05-03 00:00:00.000 | 2000-01-01 09:45:22.000 |              3 |
|    5550900 |         926 | 2018-05-03 00:00:00.000 | 2000-01-01 10:06:25.000 |              3 |
|    5550901 |         780 | 2018-05-03 00:00:00.000 | 2000-01-01 10:06:29.000 |              3 |
|    5550902 |        1887 | 2018-05-03 00:00:00.000 | 2000-01-01 10:13:48.000 |              3 |
|    5550903 |        1938 | 2018-05-03 00:00:00.000 | 2000-01-01 10:16:35.000 |              3 |
|    5550915 |        2086 | 2018-05-03 00:00:00.000 | 2000-01-01 10:54:14.000 |              3 |
|    5550916 |        1796 | 2018-05-03 00:00:00.000 | 2000-01-01 10:54:15.000 |              3 |
+------------+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
```

Now I would need to iterate/query over each row from the results to retrieve time of next event for specific user and within the same date like this:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 time FROM events
WHERE id > 5550579
AND user_id = 1887
AND date = '2018-05-03'
```

Which returns:

```sql
+-------------------------+
|          time           |
+-------------------------+
| 2000-01-01 08:41:38.000 |
+-------------------------+
```

With the given result I should compare times from first query and from second query. 
`2000-01-01 08:10:46.000` and `2000-01-01 08:41:38.000`

If the difference between these two times is greater than 60 min, I should keep result from first query, if not, row should be removed. At the end I should have table list as from first query but only with results where times between two events are larger than 60 min for that user.

I don't know if this can be achieved in pure SQL or TSQL. I know how I would do this in some programming language but not in plain SQL.

Some pseudocode as a developer I'd do:

```sql
endresult = array()
query = select id, user_id, date, time, event_type_id from events where date >= '2018-05-01' and event_type_id = 3
foreach (query as row) {
    subquery = select top 1 time from events where id > row[id] and user_id = row[user_id] and date = row[date]
    if ((subquery[time] - row[time]) > 60) {
        endresult[] = row
    }
}
```

*I updated this question with some realistic data. Also I can't explain it well as I'm a developer and not DBA expert.*

*Added with sample data, corresponding columns etc for testing purposes*

SQLFiddle link - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f83be

Comment: You haven't asked a question or provided any kind of insight as to what you want to do. But doing this row by agonizing row is not the right way to handle data. You need to explain the rules here. And also provide some details of the tables and data. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I have said what I want to achieve. In the first query I'm getting data by specified clause - date is greater than specific date and where event_type_id is e.g. 3. After that I need to check each row and pull from database next event for that user and date, and compare times. If times are greater than 60 min, I need to return that row as a final result. (I'm explaining this as a developer)

Comment: Which is incredibly vague at best. Define "next"? There is only one row in your sample data and no idea what you want as output. And as I said before your approach of getting a result set and then looping through it to further filter it down is the wrong way to handle this. But whatever, if you don't want to put in the effort to make your question clear most people aren't going to volunteer their time to help you. You get to decide how much help people give you.

Comment: I have updated my question with more details, some real example data, and also some pseudocode as I'd use if I could write some script to generate this result.

Comment: Thanks for posting some more details. Don't worry about being a database expert, the point of explaining the requirements is to understand the business rules. I think I get that now, but your approach is going to be painful for performance. You are getting one result set and then looping through it. This is going to cripple your database. The right way is to pull the data you want the first time. Is this a rolling 60 minute window or from the earliest for a given user. And why isn't the time of 10:14:48 returned for user 1887?

Comment: I know that this would be painful for DB and performance but I need to deliver some report and thus the query. As for 10:41:18 that's not returned for user 1887, that's because they have different event_type_id

Comment: Looks like event_type_id = 3 to me...all the rows in your sample do. Again, the right way is to get all the data in a single pass. The answer below is likely somewhat close.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174267/discussion-between-bosko-stupar-and-sean-lange).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the George's answer, but he hardcoded too much. This should do the trick:

```
SELECT e1.id, e1.user_id, e1.date, e1.time, e1.event_type_id FROM events e1
WHERE e1.date >= '2018-05-01'
AND e1.event_type_id = 3
and dateadd(minute,60,e1.time)>
(
    SELECT TOP 1 e2.time FROM events e2
    WHERE e2.id > e1.id
    AND e2.user_id = e1.user_id
    AND e2.date = '2018-05-03'
    order by time desc
)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Tweaked it a bit to do what it's supposed to do.

    `SELECT e1.id, e1.user_id, e1.date, e1.time, e1.event_type_id FROM events e1
    WHERE e1.date >= '2018-05-01'
    AND e1.event_type_id = 3
    AND DATEADD(minute,60,e1.time) <=
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 e2.time FROM events e2
        WHERE e2.time > e1.time
        AND e2.user_id = e1.user_id
        AND e2.date = '2018-05-03'
        ORDER BY time ASC
    )`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT id, user_id, date, time, event_type_id FROM events
WHERE date >= '2018-05-01'
AND event_type_id = 3
and dateadd(minute,60,time)>
(
    SELECT TOP 1 time FROM events
    WHERE id > 5550579
    AND user_id = 1887
    AND date = '2018-05-03'
    order by time desc
)
```

From your pseudocode I deduce you only want rows(query 1) such that the time from query 2 is 60 minutes *larger* (not smaller), correct?

Also, as Sean Lange correctly commented, what is your order-by in the second query? It means to be something meaningful if your need you combined query to be meaningful, too.

Comment: When using TOP you need to specify an order or you have no way of knowing which row will be returned. My guess though is that this is really close.

Comment: Lol, I just copy-pasted it from OP, didn't put much thought into it.